# React: Local Stylesheet was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, themes, mime-types

I'm having an issue that I haven't been able to solve from the various posts that I've been looking at, and I'm not sure what the issue is.
The error message is:

```
The stylesheet http://localhost:3000/public/css/dx.generic.GenericLightProtis.css was not loaded because its MIME type, “text/html”, is not “text/css”.
```

I'm using a mix of React Router Dom and some DevExtreme components, and have been trying to get the stylesheets (made with DE's Theme builder) to load within index.html (this is based on how DE's theme system works).

I started with

```
<head>
<link rel="dx-theme" data-theme="generic.light" href="css/dx.generic.GenericLightProtis.css" data-active="true">
<head>
```

this complained about the MIME type. I started digging around and then tried loading the stylesheet just by itself by replacing the link section with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/dx.generic.GenericLightProtis.css">
```

still MIME complaint.

I know for a fact that it's a working stylesheet, because I can import it directly into React and it styles everything as it should. I do not believe I need to link all of my code here, but here is the
Index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title></title>
<!--    <link rel="dx-theme" data-theme="generic.light" href="css/dx.generic.GenericLightProtis.css" data-active="true">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/dx.generic.GenericLightProtis.css">
</head>
<body class="dx-viewport">
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
<div id="ReactRoot"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and App.JS which containers the root base and React Router Dom stuff:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App.js';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <App/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('ReactRoot'),
);
```

And just in case, here's a quick snap of my project structure:
[image]

EDIT 1: So, looking through things, if I try to load the CSS in the webbrowser, I just get a React Router Dom page, with elements that are displayed globally.
If I look into Styles in Firefox's debugger, I can see this:
[image]

My CSS Folder is located in the public (so public/css/<file.css>) and I get the same result if I try different varations of the path (/public/css/, public/css/, /css/, css/) I am not exactly sure what the context should be in this case, since I was under the impression that /public/css/<file.css> would be the correct synthax/path.

GenerlightLightProtis.css is just a copy of the original with a shorter names, as I was testing in case there was issues with the original name.

Edit #2: I've been experementing with a few things so far and the results are as follows

1. The CSS File seem to be something specific to DevExtreme and how it's loaded, thus it can't be just loaded in the HTML's  as a CSS, it has to be a dx-theme.
2. On a blank project, with just React Router Dom and some other components, the CSS loads fine with the `current.theme` flag(?) put into index.js
3. Something within my project, even when I disable the references to other modules (Leaving App.JS to effectively render just some text) seems to mess with me calling up the CSS. I copied the working code from a blank project into my one for index.html , index.js , and App.JS , and it complains about the MIME type on load, and does not load the theme.
   I am stumped at this point.

Comment: Have you navigated to the CSS file in your browser to make sure that URL is working? If it's giving you a 404 (or similar) error page, that would explain the `text/html` MIME type.

Comment: Thanks for the response David.
if I put in the link to the CSS, I just get a blank React Router Page, that contains elements rendered on all pages. I was looking in Styles, and spotted this though (please see the edited post above)